# How does the Android build process work?

Tags: android, android-build

I've found a good article on how the Android build process works, which shows the following process:

[image]

However, I've also seen another article which says that it uses `javac` to convert all files to `.class` files, then the `dx tool` in the `adk` converts all `.class` files to `classes.dex`, like so:

[image]

Please can someone clarify which one is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look at the official document **Building and Running** http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Comment: What happens with SDK/NDK if i have a code written in it

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good explanation of [android build process](http://www.singhajit.com/android-build-process/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ajit. It's been a long time. Please up vote the Question if you liked.

Answer (score 2):

Java source code is compiled to .class files by javac, and then the class files are converted to Dalvik bytecode by the "dx" tool, which is included in the sdk 'tools'.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Build Process Image]

[Android Build System in detail](https://medium.com/mindorks/introduction-to-android-build-system-for-beginners-cfafa1ab4104)